# Convert varshar to integer but also into an AS in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, grafana

I trying to use Grafana to show some nice graph from my MySQL database.

The problem is that the column that the value have is varchar and Grafana does not like that at all. it want to have integer but I can't change that.

So I read that I have to use CAST but not sure how to make it work.
I have try but Always get error

I have this SQL code

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_updated) as time_sec,
  state as value,
  entity_id as metric
FROM states
WHERE $__timeFilter(last_updated) AND entity_id='sensor.cpu_temp'
ORDER BY time_sec ASC
```

So somehow I need to convert "state" to integer to put inside the value

So I did try

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_updated) as time_sec,
  CAST(state AS int) as value,
  entity_id as metric
FROM states
WHERE $__timeFilter(last_updated) AND entity_id='sensor.cpu_temp'
ORDER BY time_sec ASC
```

But get a error

Comment: Can we have some sample data please?

Comment: and the error message please.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay very happy that someone trying to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `CAST` as either `UNSIGNED` or `SIGNED`. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). I'm afraid I don't know why you can't cast as `INT` either. Given that's the type you declare columns as, it would seem to make sense.

Comment: YES 
I did change int to SIGNED and now it works WOW NICE HAPPY

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports *implicit* conversion, which can be quite helpful.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
(state + 0) as value,
```

The advantage (and disadvantage) of implicit conversion is that it does not generate errors when `state` is not numeric.  In that case, it just converts the leading digits (if any) to a number.